# JournalStructureServiceUtil is deprecated in Liferay 6.2

Tags: service, liferay-6, deprecated, journal

I need to know why this class JournalStructureServiceUtil is deprecated and I can't find it's replacement.

Does it have any replacement ?

I am using Liferay 6.2 e ga2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see source of [JournalStructureLocalServiceUtil.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalStructureLocalServiceUtil.java) or JournalStructureServiceUtil.java, it clearly has class comment as below.

> @deprecated As of 6.2.0, since Web Content Administration now uses the Dynamic
>   Data Mapping framework to handle structures

So [DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portlet/dynamicdatamapping/service/DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.java) or DDMStructureServiceUtil.java is it's replacement.

Comment: Thanks @Pankajkumar. I think it would be more helpful to also add a link in the source code.